# android screen supporting for different resolutions in same density

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which supports xhdpi devices.
so I created layout-xhdpi and drawable-xhdpi folders to place my drawables 
and layouts.but I'm having a problem when supporting different resolution in same density.
as an example samsung galaxy nexus and sharp IS003 detects same layout-xhdpi folder because it has same density but when I run the application in both devices,it displays buttons and 
images at different positions because both devices got different resolutions.

am I doing something wrong? should I create different folders for specific resolutions?
I have read [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation and tried to declare layouts like res/layout-sw600dp/ but it wont detect for IS03.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: have you found some solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

why you kept  `drawable-xhdpi`?. there is no android tablet with xhdpi.
[check here:](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html)
all the 10 inch tablet is only mdpi.

if you check your device density it will show only 160dpi for tablet.

there is xhdpi device for normal phone nexus S ICS.

so move all your **drawable-xhdpi** to **drawable-mdpi** and check it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I'm testing with GALAXY Nexus SC-04D and it's 720 x 1280 pixels, 4.65 inches (~316 ppi pixel density) detects layout-xhdpi so that's why I placed drawables in drawable-xdpi am I doing something wrong?

Comment: IS03 specs: 960x640 320dpi so same as nexus it's detects drawable-xhdpi and layout-xhdpi folders.I thought creating specific layers(folders)like layout_940x640 but android has been deprecated such declarations.so that's why I tried layout-sw600dp but it's only works for newer APIs.please help me if you have a solution for this problem.

Comment: did U designed thru relative layout?

Comment: actually there are bunch of framelayouts and linearlayouts given positions.is layout adjustment the solution for this?

Comment: I recommend you to go thru this link: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/